# Using multithreading in python to perform a large number of google searches

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup, information-retrieval

I am trying to calculate normalized google distance for performing text summarization of Amazon's laptop review dataset. I'm referring to this paper:

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306457316306781

The ngd_sim function below:

1. Takes two nouns `nx`, `ny` and a python dictionary `google_searches` as input,
2. Performs google search for both of them separately and stores the no. of results in `google_searches`,
3. Performs google search for `nx``ny` and stores the no. of results in `google_searches`
4. Uses the NGD formula to tell if both the nouns are similar or not.

   ```
   def ngd_sim(nx,ny,google_searches):

       beta = 0.67
       G = 3e13
       if nx in google_searches:
           print 'Using cached results...'
           num1 = google_searches[nx]
       else:
           print 'Performing google search for {}...'.format(nx)
           for i in range(3):
               try:
                   r1 = requests.get('https://www.google.co.in/search?espv=2&q={}&oq={}'.format(nx,nx))
               except:
                   continue
               break
           soup = BeautifulSoup(r1.text,"html.parser")
           res = soup.find('div',id="resultStats").text
           splitted = res.split(" ")
           if len(splitted) == 3:
               num = splitted[1]
           else:
               num = splitted[0]
           if not num:
               num1 = 1
           else:
               num1 = long(num.replace(',',''))
               google_searches[nx] = num1
       print '{} : {} results'.format(nx,num1)

       if ny in google_searches:
           print 'Using cached results...'
           num2 = google_searches[ny]
       else:
           print 'Performing google search for {}...'.format(ny)
           for i in range(3):
               try:
                   r2 = requests.get('https://www.google.co.in/search?espv=2&q={}&oq={}'.format(ny,ny))
               except:
                   continue

           soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.text,"lxml")
           res = soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text
           splitted = res.split(" ")
           if len(splitted) == 3:
               num = splitted[1]
           else:
               num = splitted[0]
           if not num:
               num2 = 1
           else:
               num2 = long(num.replace(',',''))
               google_searches[ny] = num2
       print '{} : {} results'.format(ny,num2)

       combined = nx+' '+ny

       if combined in google_searches:
           print 'Using cached results...'
           num3 = google_searches[combined]
       else:
           print 'Performing google search for {}...'.format(combined)
           for i in range(3):
               try:
                   r3 = requests.get('https://www.google.co.in/search?espv=2&q={}+{}&oq={}+{}'.format(nx,ny,nx,ny))
               except:
                   continue
           soup = BeautifulSoup(r3.text,"lxml")
           res = soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text
           splitted = res.split(" ")
           if len(splitted) == 3:
               num = splitted[1]
           else:
               num = splitted[0]
           if not num:
               num3 = 1
           else:
               num3 = long(num.replace(',',''))
               google_searches[combined] = num3
       print '{} : {} results'.format(combined,num3)
       ng = float(max([math.log(num1),math.log(num2)])-math.log(num3))/(math.log(G)-min([math.log(num1),math.log(num2)]))

       return ((1-ng >= beta),(1-ng))
   ```

I am using the following lines to populate a matrix that stores sentence similarity for all sentences in my corpus.

```
           # Generate the sentence simiarity matrix

            nouns_ls = [item for sublist in nouns_ls for item in sublist]
            n_sentences = len(nouns_ls)
            matrix1 = [[None for j in range(n_sentences)] for i in range(n_sentences)]
            for i in range(n_sentences):
                print 'I = ',i
                if not nouns_ls[i]:
                    for j in range(i+1,n_sentences):
                        matrix1[i][j] = 1e-9
                    continue
                for j in range(i+1,n_sentences):
                    print 'J = ',j
                    if not nouns_ls[j]:
                        matrix1[i][j] = 1e-9
                        continue
                    count = 0
                    for noun1 in nouns_ls[i]:
                        for noun2 in nouns_ls[j]:
                            print 'i = {}, j = {}'.format(i,j)
                            is_similar,ng_sim=ngd_sim(noun1,noun2,google_searches)
                            if is_similar:
                                count += 1
                            save_obj(google_searches,"google_searches")
                    val = float(count)/(len(nouns_ls[i])*len(nouns_ls[j]))
                    matrix1[i][j] = val
            # Make it a symmetric matrix with very small diagonal elements
            for i in range(n_sentences):
                for j in range(i+1,n_sentences):
                    matrix1[j][i] = matrix1[i][j]
            for i in range(n_sentences):
                matrix1[i][i] = 1e-9
            for i in range(n_sentences):
                for j in range(n_sentences):
                    if matrix1[i][j] == 0.0:
                        matrix1[i][j] = 1e-30
            sentence_sim = np.array(matrix1)
```

The issue I'm facing is that my code takes around 1 day to run for a single file of ~280 sentences. Is there a way to parallelize my google searches or is there some other way to calculate content similarity using NGD?

Comment: By using the multithreading module

Comment: By using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) in combo with [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/) since `requests` don't support `async`. Or easy way is to use [`grequests`](https://github.com/spyoungtech/grequests).